# Can't stack robocopy and ren in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to carry out three commands in batch at once in Windows: `robocopy`, `cd` and `ren`. An example is that I'd like to copy files to another directory and then add `.bak` after their names. I use `&&` to stack the commands:

`robocopy C:\original D:\backup && cd D:\backup && ren * *.bkp`

However, it seems like if I just type in this first bit to the command prompt:

`robocopy C:\original D:\backup && cd D:\backup`

the directory doesn't actually change. I need to insert the second command manually.

I also tried

`robocopy C:\original D:\backup && ren D:\backup\* *.bkp`

Again, it only works if I manually carry out the commands separately. If I carry out the whole command, only the first bit (`robocopy`) is carried out.

Comment: You can't use `ren` to move files to a different drive. Use `move` instead.

Comment: `cmd1 && cmd2` means "only run cmd2 if cmd1 was successful" while `cmd1 & cmd2` means "run cmd1 and then run cmd2."

Comment: @SomethingDark I'm sorry, I typed that command here wrong. There, it should be fixed now.

Comment: @SomethingDark Yes, so I *am* using `&&`. The reason is that I want to make sure the `robocopy` command completes before the `ren` command is executed. Should I be doing it like this? Or should I use a `sleep` command?

Comment: Huh?  Batch always runs commands one at a time.  You don't need to do anything special to make that happen.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I see, I did not know that! I'll use the `&` operator then. Thank you!

Comment: @SkeletonBow - Do you really want to run the next command if the current command fails? That would suggest using `&&`. One thing to take care about is that `robocopy` will return a non-zero exit code under common conditions if there are other files in the existing directory. Try the `robocopy` command alone and `ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%`.

Comment: @Liturgist I don't know very much about Batch, so I'll try to explain what I was thinking. Let's say `robocopy` takes 10 minutes to copy the files from C to D. I would want to carry out the `ren` command *after* it's done copying the files. However, I thought that if I used `&`, it would carry out both commands one after the other in quick succession and thus carry out the `ren` command before the `robocopy` was finished, and this wouldn't give me the result I desired. That's why I used `&&`. However, it seems like this isn't an issue and I can just use `&` according to the other comments...

Comment: @SkeletonBow - If a command fails, do you want to run the next one?

Comment: @Liturgist Well, actually it wouldn't make much sense to run the second command if the first one fails, but I think that it doesn't really matter. I would, however, like to be notified somehow if it failed so that I didn't think that it was successful. :)

Comment: Be careful with `robocopy` when it comes to `ErrorLevel`, because that command returns [non-zero values](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html) also in case of success, indicating whether or not files have been copied, for instance; so a command after `&&` may not be executed unexpectedly...

Comment: @SkeletonBow: you can use `&` if you like, but you could just as well put each command on a separate line.  It will do exactly the same thing, and be much easier to read.

Comment: @HarryJohnston this is exactly what I'll do. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&&` means to performs the next command only if the previous command was **successful** (or returned an errorlevel of `0`).  Similarly, `||` only performs the next command if the previous command **failed** (or returns an errorlevel greater than `0`)

Some examples would be:

```
copy null null   ||  echo this command failed

rundll32         &&  echo this command was successful

copy 1.txt 2.txt &&  echo success  ||  echo failed
```

So if you wanted to `copy` a file, `change` directory and then `rename` a file, you would do something similar to:

```
robocopy C:\original D:\backup & cd D:\backup & ren * *.bkp
```

Bear in mind that if `robocopy` fails to copy just `1` file (or more) then you can't use `&&`

*<del>A more robust option would check if `D:\backup` exists:</del>*

*<del>`(robocopy C:\original D:\backup  &  if exist "D:\backup" (pushd D:\backup & ren * *.bkp) else (echo Failed to create D:\backup 2>nul)) >nul`</del>*

*<del>It will `pushd` into the directory, and only if the `robocopy` command was successful would it rename the files, additionally hiding all messages except errors</del>*

Comment: *Bear in mind that if robocopy fails to copy just one file* - it's worse than that.  The `||` and `&&` operators, as you point out, assume that a return code of zero means success and nonzero means failure.  But Robocopy doesn't follow that convention, a return value of 4 or higher means failure.  If I remember correctly, it only returns zero if there were no files needing to be copied.